# How come we can't see supernatural creatures in today's time?

Tags: supernatural

In the Puranas and Itihasas, there are many stories featuring human interaction with supernatural creatures like Gandharvas, Apsaras, Yakshas, Rakshasas, Nagas, Asuras, Devas, Kinnaras, Kim Purushas, Pisachas, Suparnas, and other celestial beings.

How come we can't see or interact with them directly today?

Does any scripture say anything about this? Like the people of Kali Yuga cannot interact with celestial species?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90589/discussion-on-question-by-ikshvaku-how-come-we-cant-see-supernatural-creatures).

Comment: In one  biography of a Saint in Andhra Pradesh, I had read of that Saint making visible to one of his devotees, those supernatural creatures with huge bodies, but later he withdrew that display.  According to him, ordinary people cannot withstand after seeing such creatures @Ikshvaku

Comment: Please take into account that it could all just be mythology.

Comment: @Wikash_ Yes, everything is a lie, only you know the truth that it's all a lie.

Comment: No not everything is a lie.

Answer (score 2):

Tantra scriptures claim that they can be seen. Tantra provides various ways of spiritual practices to get vision of and get boons from

1.Sri Hanumanji (Who has been referred to as Kimpurusha by Sri Krishna in Srimad-Bhagavatam.

2. Yoginis,Dakinis and Apsaras (who are celestial beings)

3.Pishacha and Pisachinis

But except Sri Hanumanji,all these sadhanaas are for worldly gains and may delude the aspirant and make him fall from the spiritual path.

(Reference :Tantrik-Guru, Swami Nigamananda, Halisahar Sarasvata Math)

Comment: If they can be seen why hasn't anyone up to this date come with proof?

Comment: @Wikash_hindu yes tye saints have seen and its mentioned in their biographies. What do you mean by giving proif?

Comment: Because they are not interested in giving proofs .. Spiritual Siddhis are not matter of public display @Wikash_hindu  .. No Siidha purusha have ever demonstrated their Siddhis to public.. In spirituality proofs are subjective and not objective

Comment: @Rickross I understand but isn't their goal to bring more people towards the brahman? Then it helps if they show proof.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu What kind of proof are you looking for? And regardless, the existence of supernatural creatures does not help bring more people towards Brahman.

Answer (score 1):

Spirituality or attainment/ realisation of brahmam can be realised if you follow the path. In everyone of us the faculty to attain the knowledge of the higher world's does exists. But like a blind person cannot see the physical world, in the same way our inner eye is not open yet. Unless you perform the required sadhanas.

It was for this skepticism, that such sadhanas and paths we're kept limited to only those who seek.

So it is easy to misunderstand for a person who is skeptical or not initiated to think that such knowledge or such a higher world of beings do not exist.

Comment: "So it is easy to misunderstand for a person... " if this is the case then why do the explanations of higher worlds differ among person who claim to see such worlds?